# "Specified cast is invalid" when retrieving object from sqlite3

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite

Sorry if this has been asked before, searched for many hours now to no avail.

I'm using sqlite-net-pcl nuget. Created a table based on this class:

```
public class ProductCategory
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _prodCategory;
        private string _prodSubCategory;


        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int CategoryID { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
        public string ProdCategory { get { return _prodCategory; } set { _prodCategory = value; } }
        public string ProdSubCategory { get { return _prodSubCategory; } set { _prodSubCategory = value; } }

        public ProductCategory()
        {

        }


        public ProductCategory(string category, string subcategory)
        {
            _prodCategory = category;
            _prodSubCategory = subcategory;
        }
    }
```

I created the table this way:

```
database.CreateTableAsync<ProductCategory>().Wait();
```

This is how an instance of this class is saved into the table:

```
public Task<int> SaveCategoryAsync(ProductCategory category)
        {
            if (category.CategoryID == 0)
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(category);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(category);
            }
        }
```

And when I try retrieving the contents of the table as a list with the code below, I get a System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>> GetProductCategoriesAsync()
        {
            ObservableCollection<ProductCategory> lst = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>(await database.Table<ProductCategory>().ToListAsync());
            return lst;
        }
```

This is how the table looks like when opened with the DB Browser for SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "ProductCategory" ( "ID" integer primary key autoincrement not null , "ProdCategory" varchar , "ProdSubCategory" varchar )
```

This is the ouput of console. Couldn't find anything useful there:

```
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Globalization.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.dll [External]
03-02 19:19:31.592 E/HW-JPEG-DEC( 8873): [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
03-02 19:19:31.696 I/HwSecImmHelper( 8873): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
03-02 19:19:31.701 I/HwPointEventFilter( 8873): do not support AFT because of no config
03-02 19:19:31.861 I/OpenGLRenderer( 8873): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
WARNING: linker: 03-02 19:19:31.871 W/linker  ( 8873): /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a

/vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
03-02 19:19:32.047 I/BitmapFactory( 8873): set decoder allocator to gralloc
03-02 19:19:32.051 I/gralloc ( 8873): alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x7de66ed000): interfmt=1, stride=1024, size=6144000, usage=0x2000003
03-02 19:19:32.117 I/gralloc ( 8873): alloc_device_alloc:564: Alloc handle(0x7de66ed300): interfmt=1, stride=3072, size=55296000, usage=0x2000003
03-02 19:19:32.202 I/gralloc ( 8873): alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x7de66ed300)
03-02 19:19:32.203 I/gralloc ( 8873): alloc_device_free:586: Free handle(0x7de66ed000)
03-02 19:19:32.203 E/HW-JPEG-DEC( 8873): [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
03-02 19:19:32.309 W/art     ( 8873): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.ViewRenderer_2
03-02 19:19:32.544 I/Choreographer( 8873): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-02 19:19:33.382 I/hwaps   ( 8873): JNI_OnLoad
03-02 19:19:33.702 I/HwSecImmHelper( 8873): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
03-02 19:19:34.913 I/HwSecImmHelper( 8873): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
03-02 19:19:35.081 I/HwSecImmHelper( 8873): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
03-02 19:19:35.138 W/art     ( 8873): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.EntryRenderer
03-02 19:19:35.168 E/HW-JPEG-DEC( 8873): [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
03-02 19:19:35.169 E/HW-JPEG-DEC( 8873): [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
03-02 19:19:35.171 E/HW-JPEG-DEC( 8873): [HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete](3321): HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'ProductDB.cs:54,1' to void KetoMac.DB.ProductDB.<GetProductCategoriesAsync>d__3.MoveNext () [0x000fd].
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
03-02 19:19:35.604 W/View    ( 8873): requestLayout() improperly called by md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ScrollViewContainer{34296db V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1832} during layout: running second layout pass
03-02 19:19:35.736 W/View    ( 8873): requestLayout() improperly called by md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.NavigationPageRenderer{ac2000f V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1760 #1} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
Unhandled Exception:

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: What is the full InvalidCastException message?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by breaking that compound statement up into discrete steps and identify which specific one causes the exception

Comment: I added the output of the console. Is there another way to get more data?

Comment: Jason, which statement do you mean exactly? Table is created. SaveCategoryAsync(ProductCategory category) works as expected, product is added and sqlite automatically increments the id property. 

It is my understanding that I should receive a list from GetProductCategoriesAsync() because this is exactly what I receive from an identical table. I cannot catch a single breakpoint in the method because the statement line just breaks the debugging session with the invalidCastException error and no details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was XAML fault after all. The  element in markup of `<ListView>` was within tags of `<DataTemplate></DataTemplate>`. Adding `<ViewCell></ViewCell>` and label within in it solved the issue. Thanks to JMK in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331797/specified-cast-is-not-valid-when-binding-to-list-of-pocos#29332178) thread.

Comment: Please mark your solution as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.